# How to derive instances in recursion schemes

Tags: haskell

I am testing out some of the ideas in [this article](http://blog.sumtypeofway.com/an-introduction-to-recursion-schemes/).

I want to derive an instance of Eq for the type Term:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
data Tree a = Branch Int [a] | Leaf Int deriving (Eq, Functor, Show)
data Term f = Term (f (Term f)) deriving (Eq)
```

But get this error:

```
No instance for (Eq (f (Term f)))
      arising from the first field of ‘Term’ (type ‘f (Term f)’)
    Possible fix:
      use a standalone 'deriving instance' declaration,
        so you can specify the instance context yourself
    When deriving the instance for (Eq (Term f))
```

I tried adding a standalone deriving instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
data Tree a = Branch Int [a] | Leaf Int deriving (Eq, Functor, Show)
data Term f = Term (f (Term f))
deriving instance (Eq f) => Eq (Term f)
```

But get this error:

```
The first argument of ‘Term’ should have kind ‘* -> *’,
  but ‘f’ has kind ‘*’
In the stand-alone deriving instance for ‘(Eq f) => Eq (Term f)’
```

Now I'm stuck. How do I show that f has a kind `* -> *`? And why do I need a standalone deriving instance for `Term` but not `Tree`? Both have type variables that are not necessarily going to be instances of Eq? (`a` and `f`)

Comment: Possible typo: the definition of `Term`, does not refer to `Tree` in any way.

Comment: Try writing the instance manually and I think you will understand the problem.

Comment: @cody That was purposeful.

Comment: @ReidBarton Thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two solutions:

Using some GHC extensions `StandaloneDeriving`, `UndecidableInstances` and some others you can write:

```
deriving instance (Eq (f (Term f))) => Eq (Term f)
```

This is what [`recursion-schemes`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-4.1.2/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) does at the moment

--

Alternatively, you can use `Eq1` from [`transformers`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html#t:Eq1) or `base-4.9.0.0`

```
class Eq1 f where
    liftEq :: (a -> b -> Bool) -> f a -> f b -> Bool

eq1 :: (Eq1 f, Eq a) -> f a -> f a -> Bool
eq1 = liftEq (==)

instance Eq1 f => Eq (Term f) where
    Term a == Term b = eq1 a b
```

Reference: https://github.com/ekmett/recursion-schemes/blob/ffada24f92efd5bcfe71f7f0af3b4af057f50bd0/Data/Functor/Foldable.hs#L392

Comment: _Caveat lector_: While `Eq1` ([and friends](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Functor-Classes.html)) is probably the right way to go about this, in present GHC you have to write out the instances by hand, which is rather tedious. I'm hopeful that now `Data.Functor.Classes` is in `base` we'll get `deriving Eq1` in a forthcoming version of GHC.

Comment: `deriving-compat` has that functionality atm: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deriving-compat-0.3.1/docs/Data-Eq-Deriving.html#v:makeLiftEq