# Purpose and semantics of Eq1/Ord1 type classes

Tags: haskell

Considering the following type, how am I supposed to implement the `Eq1` instance?

```
data Foo a = Bar String | Baz a [a]

instance Eq1 Foo where
    liftEq _ (Bar a) (Bar b) = a == b -- can't use f
    liftEq f (Baz a aa) (Baz b bb) = f a b && liftEq f aa bb -- instance for lists
    liftEq _ _ _ = False
```

Is the instance above correct? Am I supposed to implement it by hand in GHC 8.0.2? There is `deriving-compat` library that uses TH, but why is it called `-compat`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point of `Eq1` and friends is providing constraints meant to be used with type constructors that take type constructors -- for instance, monad transformers, or `Fix` (cf. [*How to derive instances in recursion schemes*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38958895/2751851)) -- in a tidier manner that doesn't require extensions such as `FlexibleContexts` or `UndecidableInstances`.

> Is the instance above correct?

Yes, it is.

> Am I supposed to implement it by hand in GHC 8.0.2?

For the moment, there is no GHC-provided deriving for `Eq1`. Here is a [libraries mailing list discussion of that matter](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2016-January/026536.html).

> There is `deriving-compat` library that uses TH, but why is it called `-compat?`

I believe the "compat" is there merely because that library also offers deriving of instances that recent GHCs do provide for older GHCs.

Comment: Any hints on implementing `Ord1` by hand? I'm thinking of something like `constructorIndex :: Foo a -> Int` helper.

Comment: @nponeccop That can help if you have lots of constructors. For something small like your `Foo` I'd do it in a similar way to your `Eq1` instance. In terms of `compare`: `Bar` vs. `Baz` gives `LT`; `Baz` vs. `Bar` gives `GT`; for `Bar` vs. `Bar` you compare the strings; and for `Baz` vs. `Baz` you compare the heads, and then the tails if comparing the heads gives `EQ`.

Comment: Well, the [real type](https://github.com/ptol/oczor/blob/4e400dfcf54e1b3a8de9d3bbf13b6c5f70a3ec15/src/Oczor/Syntax/TypesF.hs#L48) has 11 constructors lol.

Comment: @nponeccop Then it definitely helps :) (How many equations you'd need without the helper? 31 at least, I reckon?)

Comment: 121 completely naive and 67 if you take anti-symmetry into account.

Comment: @nponeccop My figure of 31 was exploiting the order of the matches, but not the anti-symmetry. If you use both the order and the anti-symmetry I think you can get it down to 22.